# Why am I not logged in anymore when I click on a link from an email?

Tags: email, authentication, security

I apologise if the title is unclear; I am unsure how to phrase my issue.

I have a web app (nextjs) running locally with an authentication system (AWS Cognito).

Now, I am logged in and I navigate to this path to consult a book: http://localhost:3000/books/569

If I copy-paste that link and paste it into a new browser window, I am able to consult my book (i.e. I am logged in).

If I send myself this same link by email and I click on the link from the email (same browser, same computer), I am being redirected to the root http://localhost:3000/ (I am not logged in).

Again, sorry if this is vague but I am very much lost as to why it happens like this so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: so what you are trying to say is you try to use the same link from another computer, but it does not go to books/569 but redirects you to root. You need to modify the software you have on localhost to redirect users to log in if not logged in yet. And with out more knowledge about how your software is designed, it is not possible to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the same browser is started when you click the link in the email? And this will only work if the site uses cookie based authentication. Some email apps even have a built in browser.